# Change saved session's working directory

Tags: neovim, sessions

I have a neovim session saved using `:mks` which by default saves to a subdirectory in my project `~/project/subdir/Session.vim`. I want it to save to `~/project/Session.vim`, which I can do by running `:cd` to change directories and then running `:mks`, but every time I load up the session, it changes the working directory back to `~/project/subdir`. How can I get it to save the changed working directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of [`:mksession`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#%3Amksession) is driven by the flags you have set in [`'sessionoptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#'ssop') (alias `'ssop'`). The two flags that are likeliest to be factors here are `curdir` and `sesdir`. The former is simple, the current directory will be saved in the session data. The entry for `sesdir` in Help says:

> ```
>  sesdir     the directory in which the session file is located
>             will become the current directory
> ```

The two are not compatible (you shouldn't have them both set). `curdir` is set by default but your explanation suggests that you have `sesdir` enabled. Check your current configuration (`set ssop?`).

If you need to remove a default flag use `set ssop-=curdir` (for example) in your vimrc file.

**Update:** *Though OP has things working as needed and has accepted my answer, they still are describing behavior that doesn't jibe with how I believe Vim actually works. So I want to add some additional details with a more specific solution suggestion in case OP needs to revisit this.*

My recommendation is to use `sesdir` and then you'll see the behavior described below.

When you do `:mks /path/to/sess.vim` the working dir doesn't matter as you've specified a path. When you later do `vim -S /path/to/sess.vim` then `/path/to` will be the working dir. That's it.

What if you don't specify a path? Then `sess.vim` will be saved to the working dir of the window from which you issue the `:mks` command. *It doesn't matter how or when the working dir was configured.* It can be the "default" (whatever was set when you started Vim). Or it can be a dir you specified with *either* `:cd` or `:lcd`. Regardless, when you later start Vim with `-S /some/path/sess.vim` then, thanks to `sesdir`, the working dir will be `/some/path`.

I have verified that all of the above is accurate.

Comment: Removed `curdir` and added `sesdir` in my init.vim file. This didn't fix the problem. But then I also discovered the `:lcd` command. If I change directory with that instead of `:cd`, then it saves with the session. I'm not sure if changing `ssop` contributed to this or not, but either way, I managed to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @howardh Glad you found a resolution though what you're saying sounds strange. `:lcd` doesn't get treated specially. Though you've accepted my answer (thanks!) I've added some important new details to it...in case your current solution causes problems in the future.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. This didn't actually fix the problem. It just appeared like it did because when I change the window's working directory, it gets saved in the session file. But it only affects that one window. So if I'm reading this correctly, there's no way to make `:mks` always save to the same directory when no destination is specified, is that right?

Comment: Not natively. But it would be trivial to create a command that "wraps", let's say, a `:lcd/:cd yourdir` call and an `:mks` call into one action. If you do give an argument it can jjust call `:mks`. Then start using that instead of `:mks`. Don't know if that would work for you.